# Prove that $\sqrt{n(n + 1)} \leq n + \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: notation

Is it valid to say that since $\sqrt{n(n + 1)} > 1$ and $n + \frac{1}{2} > 1$ that we can square both sides without having to assume anything about their inequality?

Also can someone show me how with induction or strong induction?

Comment: AM-GM: $$\sqrt{n\cdot(n+1)}\leq\frac{n+(n+1)}2=n+\frac12$$

Comment: Is it not valid to square both sides?

Comment: It's not that it is invalid but it is a slightly more intrinsic argument ($x^2$ needs to be a strictly increasing function over the naturals). AM-GM is simply more general and useful.

Comment: You indeed can square both sides, but because they're both nonnegative, not because they're greater than $1$.

Comment: Yes but if one is greater than 1 at some point and one is less than 1, then one will decrease, one will increase. But if they both are greater than 1 always, then the functions are clearly monotonically increasing. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Monotonically increasing means $f(x) \leq f(y)$ whenever $x \leq y$.  You are describing $f(x) \geq x$, which is sometimes a useful relationship, but not so much in this context.  All that matters here is that $f(x) = x^2$ is monotonically increasing on $x \geq 0.$

Answer (score 7):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}<\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=n+\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Man I am so dumb. How do people get so sharp at math. My prof went over 200 induction proofs like this and then put a simple algebra problem on the exam...

Comment: It's literally the same thing as squaring both sides though @mk3009hppw

Comment: @mk3009hppw: This is the way is works for me at least. Sometimes you remember a trick sometimes you don't. Most things are blindingly obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides you get $$ n^2+n\le n^2+n+\frac {1}{4}$$ which is true for  all n.